# How to create valid public and private key for digital sign?

Tags: .net, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key, pki

How i can get free X509 Certificates with true public and private key?
I use .net to encrypt and decrypt document.
Its can import `pfx` file.
And now how i can create single `pfx` file with `public & private` for each User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [makecert and pvk2pfx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx), both get installed with visual studio.

First run makecert to get a certificate (cer file) and private key file (pvk file)

```
makecert -sv yourprivatekeyfile.pvk -n "cert name" yourcertfile.cer -b mm/dd/yyyy -e mm/dd/yyyy -r
```

where:

- -sv yourprivatekeyfile.pvk is the name of the file containing the private key.
- -n "cert name" is the name that will appear on the certificate (and in the certificate store).
- yourcertfile.cer is the name of the certificate file.
- -b  mm/dd/yyyy is the date when the certificate becomes valid.
- -e  mm/dd/yyyy is the date when the certificate expires.
- -r indicates that this will be a self-signed certificate.

One you have your two files you can combine them in to a pfx file

```
PVK2PFX –pvk yourprivatekeyfile.pvk –spc yourcertfile.cer –pfx yourpfxfile.pfx –po yourpfxpassword
```

where:

- -pvk  yourprivatekeyfile.pvk is the private key file that you created
- -spc  yourcertfile.cer is the certificate file you created
- -pfx  yourpfxfile.pfx is the name of the .pfx file that will be created.
- -po  yourpfxpassword is the password that you want to assign to the .pfx file.